# Mysql utf8_unicode_ci multilanguage support

Tags: mysql

Are these languages supported by mysql 4.1.14 if i use utf8_unicode_ci?

Australia,Austria,Belgium,Bulgaria,Canada,Czech Republic,Denmark,Estonia,Finland,France,
Germany,Greece,Hungary,Ireland,Italy,Latvia,Lithuania,Luxembourg,Malta,Netherlands
Poland,Portugal,Romania,Slovakia,Slovenia,Spain,Sweden,Switzerland,United Kingdom,United States

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html, I assume yes. You may want to do some testing through.